# Write binary file with Javascript and ADODB.Stream

Tags: javascript, base64, activex, hta

I'm currently making a HTA application and I need to save Base64-encoded ZIP archive to file.

```
var stream = new ActiveXObject('ADODB.Stream');
stream.Type = 1;
stream.Open();
stream.Write(atob(data));
stream.SaveToFile('dump.zip');
stream.Close();
```

This code throw error on stream.Write(data) `Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.` There are some solutions for VBScript, but I'm trying to make it on javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this](http://rsdn.ru/forum/web/673601.1) post

```
var stream = new ActiveXObject('ADODB.Stream');
stream.Type = 2; //Stream type - text data o_0
stream.Charset = "windows-1251"; //windows-1252 works too
stream.Write(atob(data));
stream.SaveToFile('dump.zip');
stream.Close();
```

I still don't understand why I must save binary data as text, but it works.

Comment: Because the file is "Base64-encoded"; Base64 is (plain)text representation of a (binary) file/data